# Notification sound settings dialog like WhatsApp in React Native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm developing a React Native app and I need to give the user to change the notification tone through the settings. I did search lots regarding this feature and didn't find a solution yet. So is someone have done this before, please share it with me and it will be helpful for me to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Which notification you are using? local or Push notification?

Comment: I'm using both, but here I wanted for push notification

Comment: Are you using data message or notification at FCM server side?

Comment: I'm sending the notification from my backend using firebase admin sdk

Comment: Take a look a this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload

Comment: @GiladShnoor yes, we can put our sound files on `res/raw/sound.mp3` and use it, but I need to set sounds that come with the device.

Comment: @TIJ For that, you need to use data message from backend and add logic for showing notification from that manually using custom sound uri.

Comment: @TJI you can send notification without sound and use something like react-native-track-player to play the sound you choose inside the setBackgroundMessageHandler callback. Also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862475/react-native-firebase-play-custom-sound-on-notification-arrived

Comment: @AbhayKoradiyaI actually I don't need to play custome sound, I want to give an option to change system notification sound only for this app, like WhatsApp settings -> Notifications -> Notification tone that shows the default sounds that came with the device.

Comment: @GiladShnoor could you please read my previous comment?

Comment: @TIJ I don't think I understand what you are trying to do can you please try to clarify it

Comment: @GiladShnoor I want to implement WhatsApp or Messanger like notification tone settings menu In React Native

Comment: @TIJ That much I got. I am trying to understand why the solution described in my last comment is not ok

Comment: @GiladShnoor Your answer is to play custom sound but I need to set sounds from the device notification sound list and that method not valid the app is killed

Comment: @TIJ setBackgroundMessageHandler will be called when the app is closed and you can select from the folder holding all the notification sounds